# Creating Video Slideshow From Images With Different Sizing/Aspect Ratio Using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been trying to get this to work on and off for the past month and am very frustrated, so I'm hoping someone on here could help me.  What I'm trying to do is very simple but I struggle with ffmpeg.  I basically just want to take a folder of pictures, each of which have different sizes and some may be horizontal or vertical orientation, and put them into a video slideshow where they show for maybe 5-10 seconds each.  No matter what I try, it always winds up stretching out the pictures to be out of the ratio and they just look funny.  I noticed Windows 10 Photo program does this perfectly, but I want a programmatic approach and I don't think it has a commandline feature.  Can someone help me tweak this ffmpeg commandline to work the way I need it to?  Desired video output would be 1920x1080 in this case.  Thanks!

ffmpeg -r 1/5 -start_number 0 -i "C:\Source_Directory_Pictures\Image_%d.jpg" -c:v libx264 -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" "F:\Destination_Output\Test_Output.mp4"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a combination of scale and pad to generate proportionally resized images centered onto a 1080p frame.

Use

`ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -start_number 0 -reinit_filter 0 -i "C:\Source_Directory_Pictures\Image_%d.jpg" -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:eval=frame,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1:eval=frame" -r 25 -c:v libx264 "F:\Destination_Output\Test_Output.mp4"`

Comment: I think this is finally it, thank you!  There is no way I would have been able to come up with that -vf logic that you did, but this appears to handle all different sizes, aspect ratios, orientations, etc.